# How to read logs lines and do an echo if they contain a certain string

Tags: linux, bash, scripting

Right now I have this :

```
while read p ; do
    if ("$p | awk 'print $5'") == "sshd" && ("$p | awk 'print $6'") == "Connection";do
        echo("$p")
    done
done < /log.txt
```

and the text I want to detect is "sshd" just before a "[" and "Connection" after the string ": ".

the logs line looks like this :

```
Sep 21 05:45:55 MY_MACHINE sshd[16251]: Connection from 76.127.218.159 port 41950
```

Comment: You've got a couple of good answers, but I wonder what it is you're trying to do. Are you looking at blocking SSH connection attempts? You could use something like `fail2ban` or `sshguard` for that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can simply be done with a single **`awk`** command:

```
awk '$5 ~ /^sshd/ && $6 == "Connection"' log.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just use `awk`:

`awk '$5 ~ /^sshd\[\[0-9]+\]:$/ && $6 ~ /^Connection$/{print}' /log.txt`